# How to display geometrycollection in qgis?

Tags: qgis, pgadmin-4

I have connected to the restored database in qgis but can't get the geometry collection to display, how do I get it to display?

I restored the database.
Connected to it in qgis.
The table has a geom column which is of type geometrycollection.
When viewing this table nothing is displayed, what do I need to do to get it displayed?